# Extremely Basic UIButton crashes project

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm taking a course in Xcode/Objective-C and the first thing is just a textfield, label, and button.

The three things were setup like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;
- (IBAction)DisplayText:(id)sender;
```

in the DisplayText action, it says

```
self.Label.text = self.textField.text;
```

When I crash I get this line highlighted red and it says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

```
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]))
```

I also see this when it crashes

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[ViewController asd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0x7fab3bc38c50'
```

Every time I click the button, it crashes. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you added an action to the button?

Comment: Provide details about the error when it crashes. See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: @RashwanL I have added an action. The DIsplayText action is linked with the button.

Comment: @rmaddy I added the messages that appears when it crashes

Comment: You need to go through the link I provided in my first comment so you can properly debug and find where the crash is really happening. You need to figure out where you are trying to call the `asd:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you. I searched project for whatever asd was and deleted it. Idk how it got in there but whatever it was, was causing the crash. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the debugger it will probably tell you what caused the error. This has happened to me before, due to insufficient memory (too many items on screen at once). Either way, look at the target debugger for what caused the error.